# How to reload /etc/environment without rebooting?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

`/etc/environment` is [officially](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) the correct place for system wide environment variables. But how can I **reload** the assignments in this file without rebooting or relogging?

Interestingly enough google does not help me here, aside from the dozens of blog posts suggesting to use

```
source /etc/environment
```

which obviously will **never work** because `/etc/environment` is a list of assigments (one per line) and **not** an executable script (hence the missing `export` commands in `/etc/environment` ...).

Comment: Systemwide, I have no idea. For the current shell session, you can use `for line in $( cat /etc/environment ) ; do export $line ; done`, if the file format is `key=value`.

Comment: Works for me without an `export`...

Comment: @lzkata: If a variable is already exported, it should not be necessary to export it again... If new variable that have not already been exported are added, the `export` would be necessary... (without it it is just a normal non-environment variable in the current shell, not available in child processes)

Comment: @DanielBeck thank you..plz add you comment as an answer!

Comment: does it works also on debian and centos ?

Comment: does it require user login or its settings are used also by daemons and cron jobs ?

Comment: I'm just curious why all the blog posts I see also suggest to use `source /etc/environment` when it doesn't work (for me)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

One thing you are mistaken about is that `/etc/environment` requires a reboot to reload. This is incorrect. The only time the file is read is *on login*, when the PAM stack is activated – specifically `pam_env.so`, which reads the file.

Logging out and back in would apply the changes – and in fact you ***must* do this if you want all your processes to receive the new environment**. All other "solutions"<sup>2</sup> will only apply the environment to the single shell process, but not to anything you launch through the GUI including new terminal windows.<sup>1</sup>

If you're fine with that, though – the lack of `export` commands can be compensated for with `set -a` and `set +a`. However, it still remains a poor way, as the file doesn't use quoting either. But this should work fine:

```
while read -r env; do export "$env"; done
```

---

<sup>1</sup> GNOME Session Manager provides a way to change its own environment, but only during the `Initialization` phase:

```
$ gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.SessionManager \
                -o /org/gnome/SessionManager \
                -m org.gnome.SessionManager.Setenv \
                "FOO" "bar"
Error: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.NotInInitialization: Setenv
    interface is only available during the Initialization phase
```

---

<sup>2</sup> `gdb` is not a solution, but can be used sometimes. You have to attach it to the running processes of your session manager (e.g. `gnome-session`), your window manager (e.g. `gnome-shell` or `openbox`), your taskbar/panel if any (e.g. `xfce4-panel`), and generally anything else that possibly would run stuff. For each of those processes, you need to attach `gdb` to it by PID, invoke the `putenv()` function using `p`, then detach using `q`:

```
$ sudo gdb -p $(pidof gnome-session)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1
[...]
Attaching to process 718
[...]
0x00007fc2cefed81d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

(gdb) p putenv("FOO=bar")
$1 = 0

(gdb) p putenv("BAZ=qux")
$2 = 0

(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.
Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: /usr/bin/gnome-session, process 718
```

Note that the debugger pauses the process, therefore you must attach to compositing window managers only from another tty (virtual console) or over SSH, otherwise the screen would freeze.

*In addition to that,* you should also update the environment used by dbus-daemon:

```
$ dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd FOO=bar BAZ=qux
```

For older systems:

```
$ gdbus call -e -d org.freedesktop.DBus \
                -o /org/freedesktop/DBus \
                -m org.freedesktop.DBus.UpdateActivationEnvironment \
                "{'FOO': 'bar', 'BAZ': 'qux'}"
()
```

Comment: I just tested while read -r env; do export "$env"; done on Ubuntu 16.04 and it errors.  Would you like more details?

Comment: The `while read` method reads from `stdin`, so you probably want to pipe something to it (e.g. `cat /etc/environment | while ...`). But this won't work with quote formatted environment files (`key="value"`)

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for (and trying to come up with) an elegant solution like your `read -r` for a while, to parse generic "env files" like those used with Docker etc. Here is a more complete example, which skips blank lines and lines starting with `#` (as is common in env files nowadays) and exits with an error if a line is malformed: `while read -r pair; do if [[ $pair == ?* && $pair != \#* ]]; then export "$pair" || exit 2; fi; done < SOME_ENV_FILE`

Answer (score 16):

This is not as comprehensive as the accepted answer, but if you have quoted variables in your `/etc/environment` files both previous methods (which use `export $line` somehow) will go wrong and you end up with quoted values.

- Option 1: with a temporary source-able file

`sed 's/^/export /' /etc/environment > /tmp/env.sh && source /tmp/env.sh`

- Option 2: with inline `for` (thanks @tim-jones):

`for env in $( cat /etc/environment ); do export $(echo $env | sed -e 's/"//g'); done`

- Option 3: with the `allexport` bash option (thanks @ulidtko):

`set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a;`

Comment: Shorter: eval `sed 's/^/export /' /etc/environment`

Comment: Non-temp-file version of above: `for env in $( cat /etc/environment ); do export $(echo $env | sed -e 's/"//g'); done`

Comment: Even shorter: `set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a;`.