# How to set environment variables in /etc/environment?

Tags: debian, environment-variables

I'm using Debian Jessie. I want to set some environment variables that will persist across reboots and work in non-shell environments.

I've set the following in `/etc/environment`:

```
SECRET_KEY=xxx
```

But then if I do the following, it produces nothing:

```
printenv SECRET_KEY
```

How do I set this environment variable and activate it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting. did you try logging out and back in?

Answer (score 2):

After modifying the `/etc/environment` file you need to close the shell you are working with and log back in a new shell so that the file is read and applied by the PAM stack.