# Re-login WSL Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have Ubuntu-22.04 installed in WSL2.

I changed `/etc/environment` and, as [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/339652) suggests, I need to log out and log in Ubuntu
for the changes to take place. But I'm unable to do so as WSL just seems to save its state whatever I do.

I tried:

1. `wsl --shutdown`.
2. `Restart-Service LxssManager`.
3. Restart Windows.

None of the above worked.

I noticed that in older versions WSL Ubuntu sometimes listed some additional information on login (greeting, current time, etc.) -- I figure, it does that on login, but I never see this info now, it just starts with an empty shell line, so, I guess, it never logs me in just keeping the same session somehow.

So, how can I force it to re-login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking last night, as I was deep into researching where the path is set when using Systemd (of course, `/etc/environment` by default), that it would be ironic to get a related question on the topic today.  And look - Here it is!

The problem you are seeing isn't that WSL doesn't "shut down" (it does), or even that it "saves state" (it doesn't).  The problem is simply that `/etc/environment` doesn't (normally) get processed on WSL.

This is because `/etc/environment` is a PAM construct -- It's typically read into the environment by `pam_env.so` during *login*.

However, as you've probably noticed, there's no real concept of a "login" in WSL.  It never asks for your username or password, as the real security comes from your *Windows* account and permissions.

You can force a login that invokes PAM (and thus reads `/etc/environment`) with something like:

```
sudo su - $USER
```

You might want to just set the variables in either:

- `~/.bashrc` -- If you only need them for something in an *interactive* session
- `~/.bash_profile` -- If you need them for all sessions under the "login" shell.
- Or another config file if you are using a different shell.

`/etc/environment` is really meant for variables that should be set for *all users* in a multi-user system.  WSL is really designed with a single default, developer user in mind.

> Ubuntu sometimes listed some additional information on login (greeting, current time, etc.) ..., but I never see this info now

That's the message-of-the-day functionality, and it should typically only display once a day.  Just wait until tomorrow, and you'll probably see it again.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I've also seen a lot of suggestions to edit `/etc/profile` won't it work?

Comment: @Eyjafl Yes, `/etc/profile` is sourced by the shell itself, and I'm fairly sure the default 22.04 configuration will do so under WSL.